# How to use two different bindingstrings and if one gets selected turn the other one false

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

So I am forced to use two different bidningstrings because of a tool we use to create a pdf. My goal here is when a user clicks a Yes or No button that the other corresponding bindingstring will be turned "Off"  and the one clicked turned to "Yes" I created a Jquery way of doing this but that will become insane because I would have to do this like 100x  Is there a way to do this inline with knockout I like I  did with the knockout way of styling the opacity of the buttons?

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 80px">
    <div class="col-xs-6 EntDisorderTrue"  data-bind="style:{ 'opacity' : EntDisorderTrue()=='Off' ? '.5' : '' }" >
        <label class="btn btn-success yesbtn">
            <input type="radio" value="Yes" data-bind=" checked: EntDisorderTrue " />@Global.Yes
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 EntDisorderFalse"  data-bind="style:{ 'opacity' : EntDisorderFalse()=='Off' ? '.5' : '' }" >
        <label class="btn btn-success nobtn">
            <input type="radio"  value="Yes" data-bind="checked: EntDisorderFalse" />@Global.No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery way of switching the values

```
        $(".EntDisorderFalse").click(function () {
        if (self.EntDisorderFalse() == "") {
            self.EntDisorderFalse("Yes")
            self.EntDisorderTrue("Off")
        } else if (self.EntDisorderFalse() == "Off") {
            self.EntDisorderFalse("Yes")
            self.EntDisorderTrue("Off")

        } 
    });

    $(".EntDisorderTrue").click(function () {
        if (self.EntDisorderTrue() == "") {
            self.EntDisorderTrue("Yes").css
            self.EntDisorderFalse("Off")
        } else if (self.EntDisorderTrue() == "Off") {
            self.EntDisorderTrue("Yes")
            self.EntDisorderFalse("Off")
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use knockout in many years but can show you a generic approach.

Use a common class for the False/True elements and a data attribute for the entity name

```
<div class="col-xs-6 true" data-entity="EntDisorder"...
```

Then use `[]` notation to dynamically access the appropriate method

```
$(".true").click(function () {
    var ent = $(this).data('entity'),
        trueMethodName = ent + 'True',
        falseMethodName = ent + 'False';
    if (self[trueMethodName]() == "") {
        self[trueMethodName]("Yes").css
        self[falseMethodName]("Off")
    } else if (self[trueMethodName]() == "Off") {
        self[trueMethodName]("Yes")
        self[falseMethodName]("Off")
    }
});
```

Comment: ent is undefined is that trying to get the  bindingstring EntDisorder not the value? If I can get the actual bindingstring I bet I can figure  something out